# how do I set up adb with MyTouch 4g?

Tags: usb, adb, htc-mytouch

I have a mytouch 4g running gingerbread.  I want to set up adb to work with the phone over usb, but I can' figure out how to do it.  Frankly, I don't really know anything more so I'm not sure what else to say.  Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you installed the Android SDK?  What exactly is not working?

Comment: Windows, Mac OS or Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure that "USB debugging" option is enabled on your phone by going to `Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Development`.  On some devices this option will be grayed out while your phone is connected via USB, so disconnect it first.

Next step is installing the USB drivers on your computer.  Assuming you are running Windows, the drivers for MyTouch 4G should be located on the SD Card that came with the phone.  Look for file named "HTCDriver.exe" then copy to your PC and execute it.  If you can't find that file, look for the drivers on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&q=mytouch%204g%20drivers%20for%20windows%207).

After you successfully install the drivers, download and install the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).  Pick a folder that's easy to type, such as `"C:\AndroidSDK"` for example.

Now open Windows Command prompt by going to Start -> Run, typing "cmd" (without quotes) and pressing Enter.  In the Command Prompt window type in `cd C:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools` and press Enter.  Connect your MT4G to the PC via USB, and in the command prompt type in `adb devices` and press Enter.

If everything was correctly installed you should see messages like these:

> * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
>   * daemon started successfully *
>   List of devices attached
>   XXXXXXXXXXX    device

where "XXXXXXXXXX" is a combination of letters and numbers, signifying your phone's ID.

This means ADB is seeing your phone, and you can now issue commands to it.

Answer (score -1):

Try HTC Sync Manager

http://www.theandroidsource.com/my-touch-4g-root-rooting-roms-hacks-overclocking-etc/292-latest-htc-mytouch-4g-sync-driver-download.html

https://support.htc.com/alerts_downloads/en/HTC_Sync_and_Sync_Manager_for_all_HTC_Android_Phones

joslloyd

Comment: Link-only answers are not recommended, because if the URL dies or changes, the answer is worthless. Please edit your answer to include at least an outline of what the links contain.